# How to order nested SQL SELECT on SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have written an SQL script that should get X entries before a user id, ordered by registration_date desc on ordered db table based on registration date.

To be more concrete, lets say that these are some entries on the ordered db:

```
    id      | Name                  | Email                           | registration_data
    3939    | Barbara Hayes         | barbara.hayes@example.com       | 2019-09-15T23:39:26.910Z
    689     | Noémie Harris         | noemie.harris@example.com       | 2019-09-14T21:39:15.641Z
    2529    | Andrea Iglesias       | andrea.iglesias@example.com     | 2019-09-13T02:59:08.821Z
    3890    | Villads Andersen      | villads.andersen@example.com    | 2019-09-12T06:29:48.708Z
    3685    | Houssine Van Sabben   | houssine.vansabben@example.com  | 2019-09-12T02:27:08.396Z
```

I would like to get the users over id 3890. So the query should return

```
689     | Noémie Harris         | noemie.harris@example.com       | 2019-09-14T21:39:15.641Z
2529    | Andrea Iglesias       | andrea.iglesias@example.com     | 2019-09-13T02:59:08.821Z
```

The raw SQL that I wrote is this:

```
SELECT * from (
        SELECT id, name, email, registration_date FROM public.users
        WHERE users.registration_date > (SELECT registration_date FROM users WHERE id = 3890)
        order by registration_date
        limit 2 )
    as a
order by registration_date desc
```

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=48487581e3f6b37aef5135f047b53611).

I tried to implement the SqlAlchemy code with no luck. I believe that I am making a mistake on the subquery. This is what i have done so far.

```
registration_date_min = db.query(User.registration_date) \
    .order_by(User.registration_date) \
    .filter(User.id == ending_before).first()

users_list = db.query(User) \
    .filter(User.registration_date > registration_date_min) \
    .order_by('registration_date').limit(limit).subquery('users_list')

return users_list.order_by(desc('registration_date'))
```

P.s the `ending_before` represents a user_id. Like `3890` in the example.
Any ideas on the SqlAlchemy part would be very helpful!

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5QwQEm real quick ?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The example with the table is just ordered by date desc, that's why the specific dates. To tell you the truth, I was a bit buffled of what you meant with the samples dates, that's why I posted codeshare, to discuss  it a bit faster there. On the bright side I tried your solution and it worked !

Comment: On mobile right now. I put the query onto a dbfiddle and see I must have gotten the userids mixed up. :-/ Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `registration_date_min` query has already been executed; you have a row with one column there. Remove the `first()` call; it executes the `SELECT` and returns the first row.

As you are selecting by the primary key, there is only ever going to be a single row and you don't need to order it. Just use:

```py
registration_date_min = db.query(User.registration_date).filter(
    User.id == ending_before
)
```

That's now a query object and can be used directly in a comparison:

```py
users_list = (
    db.query(User)
    .filter(User.registration_date > registration_date_min)
    .order_by(User.registration_date)
    .limit(limit)
)
```

You can then [*self-select* with `Query.from_self()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_self) from that query to apply the final ordering:

```py
return user_list.from_self().order_by(User.registration_date.desc()))
```

This produces the following SQL (on SQLite, other dialects can differ):

```sql
SELECT anon_1.users_id AS anon_1_users_id, anon_1.users_name AS anon_1_users_name, anon_1.users_email AS anon_1_users_email, anon_1.users_registration_date AS anon_1_users_registration_date 
FROM (SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name, users.email AS users_email, users.registration_date AS users_registration_date 
FROM users 
WHERE users.registration_date > (SELECT users.registration_date AS users_registration_date 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = ?) ORDER BY users.registration_date
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?) AS anon_1 ORDER BY anon_1.users_registration_date DESC
```

If I use the following model with `__repr__`:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    registration_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User({self.id}, {self.name!r}, {self.email!r}, {self.registration_date!r}>"
```

and print the query result instances I get:

```
<User(689, 'Noémie Harris', 'noemie.harris@example.com', datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 14, 21, 39, 15, 641000)>
<User(2529, 'Andrea Iglesias', 'andrea.iglesias@example.com', datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 13, 2, 59, 8, 821000)>
```